# ruby on rails ferret search:.only 10 records are getting from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**ruby on rails ferret search:.only 10 records are getting from table.For pagination i did it ,but only 10 records are getting even though there exists more records satisfying the search condition.if any of you know how to solve this,please reply.** no limit is given.if it is not a ferret search all records are getting from table , and pagination is working

the code is:

**@search_sd_ticket_result=ServiceDeskTicket.find_with_ferret(params[:sd_ticket][:servicedeskticket]).paginate :per_page =>5, :page=>params[:page]**

Answer (score 0):

There will be default limit in your code. so it will return only 10 records at a time.please put your code here so that one could able to tell you what is the exact problem.

Do you use **:limit=> 10**    *or*     **:per_page => 10** somewhere in your code.

Ref link:- http://blog.zmok.net/articles/2006/10/18/full-text-search-in-ruby-on-rails-3-ferret

Comment: you used :per_page =>5.
so you should not get more that 5 records at a time change it to :per_page =>100 if you want 100 recorde per page.

Comment: :limit => :all     generated all the records.now working.

find_with_ferret(      ,:limit => :all).paginate :per_page =>10, :page=>params[:page]